# Google Adwords PHP SDK userAgent validation Error(V201406)

Tags: google-app-engine

> An error has occurred: Validation failed for [userAgent] with value
>   []: The property userAgent is required and cannot be NULL, the empty
>   string, or the default [userAgent]

How can I resolve this exception?

---

Code example:

```
require_once 'Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/Lib/AdWordsUser.php';

$user = new AdWordsUser();
$user->LogDefaults();
$targetingIdeaService = $user->GetService('TargetingIdeaService', 'v201406');
```

Comment: Can you include some code please? The error is saying that something is null. Make sure everything has a value, if not back track and see why its being set to null.

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems indeed that you're creating an object with a null property.  You might want to include, as Bruyere pointed out, some code to help us :)

Comment: Usually it's correct that we need code to see the problem, though in this case, the problem is that the values are read from an `.ini` file declared in the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Adwords SDK version 201406 requires you to set userAgent to a non-empty string by which you can identify your API Request and Google Team can identify where from the Request comes if any problem arises. Put any valid name to userAgent in the auth.ini file.